# Не передается email в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, нажимаю зарегистрировать пользователя, все данные передаются, кроме email, что это может быть?

```
include ("conf4b.php");

 // файл bd.php должен быть в той    же папке, что и все остальные, если это не так, то просто измените путь
// проверка на существование пользователя с таким же логином

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE    login='$login'", $db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
    exit("Извините, введённый вами логин уже    зарегистрирован. Введите другой логин.");
}

//    если такого нет, то сохраняем данные

$result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (login,password,avatar,email,date)    VALUES('$login','$password','$avatar','$email',NOW())");

//    Проверяем, есть ли ошибки

if ($result2 == 'TRUE') {
    $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE login='$login'", $db); //извлекаем    идентификатор пользователя. Благодаря ему у нас и будет уникальный код    активации, ведь двух одинаковых идентификаторов быть не может.
    $myrow3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
    $activation = md5($myrow3['id']) . md5($login); //код активации аккаунта. Зашифруем    через функцию md5 идентификатор и логин. Такое сочетание пользователь вряд ли    сможет подобрать вручную через адресную строку.
    $subject = "Подтверждение регистрации"; //тема сообщения
    $message = "Здравствуйте! Спасибо за регистрацию на citename.ru\nВаш логин:    " . $login . "\n
                Перейдите    по ссылке, чтобы активировать ваш    аккаунт:\nhttp://localhost/test3/activation.php?login=" . $login . "&code=" . $activation . "\nС    уважением,\n
                Администрация    citename.ru"; //содержание сообщение
    mail($email, $subject, $message, "Content-type:text/plane;    Charset=windows-1251\r\n"); //отправляем сообщение
    echo "Вам на E-mail выслано письмо с cсылкой, для подтверждения регистрации.    Внимание! Ссылка действительна 1 час. <a href='index.php'>Главная    страница</a>"; //говорим о    отправленном письме пользователю
}
```

### Регистрация

```
<form action="save_user.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <!-- save_user.php - это адрес обработчика. То есть, после нажатия на кнопку "Зарегистрироваться", данные из полей отправятся на страничку save_user.php методом "post" -->
   <p>
      <label>Ваш логин *:<br></label>
      <input name="login" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15">
   </p>
   <!-- В текстовое поле (name="login" type="text") пользователь вводит свой логин -->  
   <p>
      <label>Ваш пароль *:<br></label>
      <input name="password" type="password" size="15" maxlength="15">
   </p>
   <!--    В поле для паролей (name="password" type="password") пользователь вводит свой пароль -->  
   <p>
      <label>Ваш E-mail    *:<br></label>
      <input name="email"    type="text" size="15" maxlength="100">
   </p>
   <!-- Вводим е-майл -->  
   <!-- В поле для паролей (name="password" type="password") пользователь вводит свой пароль -->  
   <p>
      <label>Выберите аватар. Изображение должно быть формата jpg, gif или png:<br></label>
      <input type="FILE" name="fupload">
   </p>
   <!-- В переменную fupload отправится изображение, которое    выбрал пользователь. --> 
   <p>Введите    код с картинки *:<br>          
   <p><img    src="code/my_codegen.php"></p>
   <p><input    type="text" name="code"></p>
   <!-- В “code/my_codegen.php” генерируется    код и рисуется изображение --> 
   <p>
      <!-- В переменную fupload отправится изображение, которое выбрал пользователь. --> 
   <p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться">
      <!-- Кнопочка (type="submit") отправляет данные на страничку save_user.php  -->  
   </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Функции `mysql_` устарели. Не используйте их! P.S. Уточняйте свой вопрос, потому что сейчас не ясно куда, когда и зачем он не передается.

Comment: А html можно увидеть? Может у него `name` не стоит. В консоли видно что улетает email? И вообще он хоть из html передается?)

Comment: кинул html в начало темы

Comment: @ZOymyng: А где ваш `$_POST['email']` в файле `conf4b.php`? В общем, непонятно откуда у вас берётся переменные `$email`, `$login`, `$password`  и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

всем спс, забыл указать просто переменную email

```
      if (isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login'];    if ($login == '') { unset($login);} } //заносим    введенный пользователем логин в переменную $login, если он пустой, то    уничтожаем переменную
          if    (isset($_POST['password'])) { $password=$_POST['password']; if ($password    =='') { unset($password);} }
          //заносим введенный    пользователем пароль в переменную $password, если он пустой, то уничтожаем    переменную
          if (isset($_POST['code'])) { $code = $_POST['code']; if    ($code == '') { unset($code);} } //заносим    введенный пользователем защитный код в переменную $code, если он пустой, то    уничтожаем переменную
          if (empty($login) or empty($password)or empty($code)) //если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем    ошибку и останавливаем скрипт
          {
          exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и    заполните все поля!"); //останавливаем    выполнение сценариев
          }

          if    (isset($_POST['email'])) { $email = $_POST['email']; if ($email == '') {    unset($email);} } //заносим введенный пользователем e-mail, если он    пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
 if    (empty($login) or empty($password)or empty($code) or empty($email)) 

            //добавим    переменную с e-mail адресом
            //если    пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку и останавливаем    скрипт 
            {

            exit    ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все    поля!"); //останавливаем    выполнение сценариев
            }
            if    (!preg_match("/[0-9a-z_]+@[0-9a-z_^\.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/i", $email)) //проверка    е-mail адреса регулярными выражениями на корректность
            {exit    ("Неверно введен е-mail!");}
```